# How to use PIL to make colored areas white-ish while leaving black areas black?

Tags: python-imaging-library

I have an application where the information I need in scanned images is solid black, but there are extraneous marks that could be in various shades of blue, red, or green. I need to eliminate the extraneous marks or at least greatly reduce their prominence (that is, make them closer to white.)

I have tried converting the image to grayscale, but the extraneous mark still shows too much in gray. I have also tried ImageEnhance.Color with values around 0.25, which, like converting to grayscale, left me with a gray extraneous mark.

Is there a PIL function that does what I want?

I am sure there is a solution that indexes through the pixels, adjusting those where the color channels have substantially different values by raising the value of the channels in the pixel with lower values but I am hoping for a faster result.

Comment: Please share representative images. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a brute-force solution to my request. It is slow.

```
from pathlib import Path
from PIL import Image
import statistics
p = Path(__file__).parent / <<before image name>>
image = Image.open(p)
image.load()
image.show()


ratio = 1.2  # threshold for brightest color / average color
for x in range(image.width):
    for y in range(image.height):
        pixel = image.getpixel((x, y))
        avg = statistics.mean(pixel)
        color_high = sorted(pixel)[-1]
        if color_high > ratio * avg:
            image.putpixel((x,y), ((int(avg),) * 3))
image.show()
```

Here is the before image:  [image: before image]
Here is the after image:  [image: after image]

Comment: Why didn't you add your image to your question like I asked and get a fast method?